# Cannot created stored procedure but everything within runs perfectly fine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to create a stored procedure but every time I try to apply it won't let me and throws the following error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '​ CREATE DEFINER=`Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `culls_&_deactivation`() BEGIN       D' at line 1

I have tried everything including running each part of the procedure and they all work. But sometimes the insert will fail and sometimes the create fails so I am not entirely sure what the issues are.

Also for reference I am using MySql 8.0.17

```
DELIMITER $$
​
CREATE DEFINER=`Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `culls_and_deactivations`()
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `metrics`.`tempvault`;

    CREATE TABLE `metrics`.`tempvault`(
        vault_date DATE DEFAULT NULL
    ,   matterid varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
    ,   MatterName TEXT
    ,   AccountName TEXT
    ,   owner_REP TEXT
    ,   valt TEXT
    ,   mrr decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
    ,   GbHosted float DEFAULT NULL
    ,   company_profile__c TEXT 
    ,   week_start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL
    ,   week_end_date DATE DEFAULT NULL
    ,   month_and_year varchar(30) default NULL
    );
​
    INSERT INTO metrics.tempvault
​
    SELECT 
        CAST(scsdr.begin_date__c AS date)
    ,   m.id
    ,   m.Name AS MatterName
    ,   a.Name AS AccountName
    ,   CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS owner
    ,   "VAULT" AS Type
    ,   NULL AS mrr
    ,   dgh.GbHosted AS GbHosted
    ,   a.company_profile__c
    ,   du.week_start_date
    ,   du.week_end_date
    ,   du.month_and_year
    FROM metrics.sf_matter__c m
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_cold_storage_date_range__c scsdr
        ON scsdr.matter__c = m.id
    INNER JOIN metrics.daily_gb_hosted dgh
        ON dgh.matterid = m.id
        #AND dgh.date_value = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
        AND dgh.date_value = DATE_ADD(CAST(scsdr.begin_date__c AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
    INNER JOIN metrics.daily_matter_contract_mapping dmcm
        ON dmcm.matterid = m.id
        AND dmcm.date_value = CAST(scsdr.begin_date__c AS DATE)
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_contract c
        ON c.id = dmcm.contractid
    INNER JOIN date_utility du
        ON du.date_value = CAST(scsdr.begin_date__c AS DATE)
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_account a
        ON a.id = c.billingaccount__c
    LEFT JOIN metrics.sf_sf_user u
        ON u.id = m.salesperson__c
    WHERE 1=1
        AND CAST(scsdr.begin_date__c AS date) >= '2018-01-01'
        AND c.type__c = 'Transactional';
​
​
​
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE) AS Date
        ,   m.id AS matterid
        ,   m.Name AS MatterName        
        ,   a.Name AS AccountName  
        ,   CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS owner
        ,   "DEACTIVATION" AS Type
        ,   mmmts.mrr AS mrr
        ,   dgh.GbHosted AS GbHosted 
        ,   a.company_profile__c
        ,   du.week_start_date
        ,   du.week_end_date
        ,   du.month_and_year
        FROM metrics.sf_matter__c m
        INNER JOIN metrics.daily_gb_hosted dgh
            ON dgh.matterid = m.id
            #AND dgh.date_value = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
            AND dgh.date_value = DATE_ADD(CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
        INNER JOIN metrics.daily_matter_contract_mapping dmcm
            ON dmcm.matterid = m.id
            #AND dmcm.date_value = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
            AND dmcm.date_value = CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE)
        INNER JOIN metrics.sf_contract c
            ON c.id = dmcm.contractid
        INNER JOIN date_utility du
            ON du.date_value = CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE)
        INNER JOIN metrics.sf_account a
            ON a.id = c.billingaccount__c
        LEFT JOIN metrics.sf_sf_user u
            ON u.id = m.salesperson__c
        LEFT JOIN metrics.matter_monthly_mrr_time_series mmmts
            ON mmmts.matter_id = m.id
            AND mmmts.date_value = du.month_end_date
        WHERE 1=1
            AND CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01'
        #AND gbHosted > 10
            AND c.type__c = 'Transactional'
        GROUP BY CAST(m.deactivationdate__c AS DATE), m.Name, a.Name
        ) AS t1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            MIN(CAST(d.dateadded__c AS DATE)) AS Date
        ,   m.id AS matterid
        ,   m.Name AS MatterName 
        ,   a.Name AS AccountName
        ,   CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS owner
        ,   "CULL" AS Type
        ,   mmmts.mrr AS mrr
        ,   MAX(dgh.GbHosted) AS GbHosted
        ,   a.company_profile__c
        ,   du.week_start_date
        ,   du.week_end_date
        ,   du.month_and_year
        FROM metrics.sf_matter__c m
        INNER JOIN metrics.sf_dataset__c d
            ON m.id = d.matter__c
            AND d.data_size__c < 0
        INNER JOIN metrics.daily_gb_hosted dgh
            ON dgh.matterid = m.id
            AND dgh.date_value = DATE_ADD(CAST(d.dateadded__c AS DATE), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
        INNER JOIN metrics.daily_matter_contract_mapping dmcm
            ON dmcm.matterid = m.id
            AND dmcm.date_value = CAST(d.dateadded__c AS DATE)
        INNER JOIN metrics.sf_contract c
            ON c.id = dmcm.contractid
        INNER JOIN date_utility du
            ON du.date_value = CAST(d.dateadded__c AS DATE)
        INNER JOIN metrics.sf_account a
            ON a.id = c.billingaccount__c
        LEFT JOIN metrics.sf_sf_user u
            ON u.id = m.salesperson__c
        LEFT JOIN metrics.matter_monthly_mrr_time_series mmmts
            ON mmmts.matter_id = m.id
            AND mmmts.date_value = du.month_end_date
        WHERE 1=1
            AND CAST(d.dateadded__c AS DATE) >= '2018-01-01'
            AND data_size__c < 0
            AND c.type__c = 'Transactional'
        GROUP BY du.month_and_year, a.Name, m.Name
        ) AS t2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM metrics.tempvault tv
    #GROUP BY tv.month_and_year, tv.AccountName, tv.MatterName
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
        CAST(spc.createddate AS date)
    ,   m.id AS matterid
    ,   m.Name AS MatterName
    ,   a.Name AS AccountName
    ,   CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS owner
    ,   "VAULT" AS Type
    ,   NULL AS mrr
    ,   SUM(spc.datasize__c) AS GbHosted
    ,   a.company_profile__c
    ,   du.week_start_date
    ,   du.week_end_date
    ,   du.month_and_year
    FROM metrics.sf_matter__c m
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_partialvault__c spc
        ON spc.matter__c = m.id
    INNER JOIN metrics.daily_matter_contract_mapping dmcm
        ON dmcm.matterid = m.id
        AND dmcm.date_value = CAST(spc.createddate AS DATE)
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_contract c
        ON c.id = dmcm.contractid
    INNER JOIN date_utility du
        ON du.date_value = CAST(spc.createddate AS DATE)
    INNER JOIN metrics.sf_account a
        ON a.id = c.billingaccount__c
    LEFT JOIN metrics.sf_sf_user u
        ON u.id = m.salesperson__c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT matterid as MATTERID, month_and_year AS MY
        FROM metrics.tempvault
        GROUP BY matterid, month_and_year
        ) AS tv ON tv.MATTERID = m.id AND tv.MY = du.month_and_year
    WHERE 1=1
        AND CAST(spc.createddate AS date) >= '2018-01-01'
        AND c.type__c = 'Transactional'
        AND tv.MATTERID IS NULL
        AND tv.MY IS NULL
    GROUP BY du.month_and_year, a.Name, m.Name
        )AS t3;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS metrics.tempvault;
​
END $$
​
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Documentation indicates you should be using single quotes for definer, not `. Also, what preceeds the CREATE; in my experience, MySQL usually complains about where it starts having problems, which suggests it didn't even like the CREATE.

Comment: Sidenote: Be careful with that "tempvault" technique, if the procedure is called at the same time by multiple connections they will interfere with each other. You may end up needing to rework the logic so a true TEMPORARY table can be used.

Comment: We are seeing the `DELIMIITER ;` statement at the end, but the `DELIMITER $$` statement is omitted from the beginning. Is there a specific reason for that? To make us think that the statement wasn't issued? (Maybe the statement isn't required in mysql-workbench, because it's supplied automatically?)

Comment: No Its there but the formatting wasn't showing it for some reason. I have fixed the snippet above. But in the code I do have it and it still does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid '&' in the name of procedure.